# OneDrive JavaScript SDK v7 file picker doesn't work with adfs

Tags: onedrive

When opening the picker, it keeps spinning, and the following is displayed in the console.

---

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?%24select=mySite

[OneDriveSDK] calling xhr failure callback, status: 401 Array[1]
  OneDrive.js:2

Uncaught Error: [OneDriveSDK Error] missing windowState from picker response
  OneDrive.js:2

---

I tried using the demo picker at https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm - and that doesn't work either!

It seems that ADFS is the root cause. User accounts that use ADFS, doesn't work, but others works like a charm.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issues